# arrange item according to max height of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to arrange `li` according to max height of div, if there is more item then item automatically set right side.

like,

```
-------------
  1   4  7
  2   5  8
  3   6
-------------
```

suggest me a better way using css or using js.

I try this,but it not work proper.

```css
ul {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(255,0,0,0.4),
      rgba(255,0,0,0.4)
    ),
    url(http://placekitten.com/g/100/100);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like [Multiple column lists using one <ul>](http://csswizardry.com/2010/02/mutiple-column-lists-using-one-ul/)?

Answer (score 1):

From [CSS tricks - Guide to Responsive-Friendly CSS Columns](https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/):

> Use `column-count` and `column-width` together for the best control over
>   CSS columns. You can declare each property or use the shorthand
>   `columns`.
>
> When both properties are declared, **`column-count` is the maximum number
>   of columns and `column-width` is the minimum width for those columns**.

but you don't have a maximum number of columns, more like a maximum height and that doesn't seem to work well.

---

With **flexbox** and its multiline wrap magic (edit: multi*column* here :) and it could be one or the other in reverse), you get the expected result:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* and then define:
  - flex-flow
  - align-items (vertically here)
  - align-content maybe (horizontally here)
  according to your style needs
  => https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
  */
  max-height: 306px;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(255,0,0,0.4),
      rgba(255,0,0,0.4)
    ),
    url(http://placekitten.com/g/100/100);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid white;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Compatibility: IE10+
I'll let you play with Autoprefixer for IE10 and old versions of browsers because I'm fed up with the 3 successive drafts of this wonderful spec ^^

Very useful **resource**: [CSS Tricks flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
**Codepen** with above code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwJYjP

Comment: hello this is work but i can not set width auto of parent of ul, there is no fix how many column is there, i want to set `height*width = auto` of parent div of ul.